# Reset 2 different forms

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to reset the 2 functions from 1 button with a function called resetFunctions() but nothing happens. The 2 other resets are working because I need them to reset only on function. I have always seen reset for each function so I am not sure if this can happens.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function result() {
   document.getElementById('ansCAL').value = calculate() + calculate1();
}
function populate(select1, select2)
{
    var Brand1 = document.getElementById(select1);
    var Brand2 = document.getElementById(select2);
    Brand2.innerHTML = "";
    if(Brand1.value == "Chevy")
    {
        var optionArray = ["|","1000|Camaro","2000|Corvette","3000|Impala"];//The | means a blank space, camaro is the label, Camaro is the value, ex. value 1000 and corvette is the label
    }
    else if(Brand1.value == "Dodge")
    {
        var optionArray = ["|","4000|Avanger","5000|Challengere","6000|Charger"];
    }
    else if(Brand1.value == "Ford")
    {
        var optionArray = ["|","7000|Mustang","8000|Shelby","focus|Focus"];
    }
    for(var option in optionArray)//the options within the optionArray
    {
        var pair = optionArray[option].split("|");//in tha variable pair is stored both value and label
        var newOption = document.createElement("option");// option in the bracket is used to create new options or you can insert divs paragraph etc
        newOption.value = pair[0];//pair 0 gives the value
        newOption.innerHTML = pair[1];//pair 1 gives the label
        Brand2.options.add(newOption);
    }
}
//second function
function calculate() {
    var Brand1 = 0;
    var Brand2 = 0;
    Brand1 = document.getElementById('slct1').value;
    Brand2 = document.getElementById('slct2').value;
    multi=document.getElementById('amount').value;
    total=parseInt((Brand2)*multi/100);
    document.getElementById('answer').value=total;
    /*document.getElementById("ansCAL").innerHTML = "<br>Total amount " + (total + total1);*/
}
//second Main function
function populate1(Select1a, Select2a)
    {
        var Brand1a = document.getElementById(Select1a);
        var Brand2a = document.getElementById(Select2a);
        Brand2a.innerHTML = "";
        if(Brand1a.value == "Chevy")
    {
        var optionArray = ["|","1000|Camaro","2000|Corvette","3000|Impala"];//The | means a blank space, camaro is the label, Camaro is the value, ex. value 1000 and corvette is the label
    }
    else if(Brand1a.value == "Dodge")
    {
        var optionArray = ["|","4000|Avanger","5000|Challengere","6000|Charger"];
    }
    else if(Brand1a.value == "Ford")
    {
        var optionArray = ["|","7000|Mustang","8000|Shelby","focus|Focus"];
    }
        for(var option in optionArray)//the options within the optionArray
        {
            var pair = optionArray[option].split("|");//in tha variable pair is stored both value and label
            var newOption = document.createElement("option");// option in the bracket is used to create new options or you can insert divs paragraph etc
            newOption.value = pair[0];//pair 0 gives the value
            newOption.innerHTML = pair[1];//pair 1 gives the label
            Brand2a.options.add(newOption);
        }
    }
//second function
function calculate1() {
    var Brand1a = 0;
    var Brand2a = 0;
    Brand1a = document.getElementById('slct1a').value;
    Brand2a = document.getElementById('slct2a').value;
    multi=document.getElementById('amount1').value;/*to change accordingly amount1*/
    total1=parseInt(((Brand2a)*multi)/100);
    document.getElementById('answer1').value=total1;/*to change accordingly amount1*/
    document.getElementById("ansCAL").innerHTML = "<br>Total amount " + (total + total1);
}
function resetFunctions() {
    document.getElementById("slct2a").reset();
    document.getElementById("slct2a").reset();
}
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form>
    Choose Your Car:
    <select id="slct1" name="slct1" onchange="populate('slct1','slct2')">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="Chevy">Chevy</option>
        <option value="Dodge">Dodge</option>
        <option value="Ford">Ford</option>
    </select>

    Choose Type of Car:
    <select id="slct2" name="slct2">

    </select>
    <label>&nbsp;Amount&nbsp;<input type="number" name="amount" id="amount" size="1" onkeyup="result()"/>   (g)&nbsp;</label>
    <label>&nbsp;Total&nbsp;<input type="number" name="answer" id="answer" size="1"/></label>   
    <input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset"/>
    <br><br><br>
    <hr>
    <br>
    </form>
    <!--Starts 2 selection-->
    <form>
        Choose Your Car:
    <select id="slct1a" name="slct1a" onchange="populate1('slct1a','slct2a')"><!--changed accordingly increased a after slct1a-->
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="Chevy">Chevy</option>
        <option value="Dodge">Dodge</option>
        <option value="Ford">Ford</option>
    </select>

    Choose Type of Car:
    <select id="slct2a" name="slct2a">

    </select>
    <label>&nbsp;Amount&nbsp;<input type="number" name="amount1" id="amount1" size="1" onkeyup="result()"/>     (g)&nbsp;</label>       <!--changed accordingly increased 1 after calculate-->
    <label>&nbsp;Total&nbsp;<input type="number" name="answer1" id="answer1" size="1"/></label>   
    <input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset"/>
    <br><br><br>
    <p id="ansCAL"></p>
    </form>
    <input type="button" onclick="resetFunctions()" value="Reset">
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Both your resets are resetting the same thing.

Comment: Every reset is resetting its function but I want that (<input type="button" onclick="resetFunctions()" value="Reset">) resets both functions.

Comment: To clarify, your `resetFunctions` has `document.getElementById("slct2a").reset();` on the first line when it should be `document.getElementById("slct1a").reset();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made small changes for you, check this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/papadpqx/9/

I fixed this for you, now everything is working.
next time you should try a bit yourself and not ask people to do your work for you.

this is all that was needed for your solution:

```
function resetFunctions() {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.forms,function(el,idx,array){
        el.reset();
    });
    result();
}
```

Comment: Great works fine. The single reset buttons of each functions that reset only one function, when clicked are not updating the (<p id="ansCAL"></p>). I mean if the 2 functions had a total sum of let say 100 of 50 each and one reset button has been clicked it is not updating the amount. It remains 100.

Comment: it's not working in fiddle but if you take only my function and put it in your code everything will work

Comment: Your function is working fine but the function you gave me and the other single reset buttons are not resetting the (<p id="ansCAL"></p>). The amount remains the same and it is not being updated

Comment: Because a P tag is not part of the form, change the p tag to be input text who is read only and it will reset as well

Comment: I changed the p to input text but it is not working. I get NaN. How do I reset it manually from your function?

Comment: Add the line `document.getElementById("ansCAL").textContent = "";`

Comment: Please do not give up as I really need it to work properly.

Comment: I have done your last code with the result(); and (<p id="ansCAL"></p>)works perfect but every time I rest the other reset buttons nothing changes in (<p id="ansCAL"></p>). I mean it remains as it was before.

Comment: You need to call result also when you click the single reset buttons. This is something you must try yourself!

Comment: Okay I will and great Thanks for your help. I think I have to edit your code for the other 2 reset buttons.

Comment: I am new to stack overflow. How do I mark this thread as answered?

Comment: click on the check mark next to my answer and press the up arrow next to my answer

Comment: Thanks my friend I did

Comment: actually you didn't, you see the 0 next to my code? press the V under it and the button up over it it should say 1 and have green check mark